# How to find that I am rooted with Systemless

Tags: rooting, supersu, systemless-root

I have flashed, SUPER SU 2.79 SR1 on Oneplus 3 running OOS 4.0 (Nougat 7.0). How to find that I am rooted in systemless mode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have systemless root and a few ways

- The superuser su binary will not be found in  `/system/xbin/`, like in normal system-based root. See 
  [Systemless Root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132753/131553)
- On your terminal emulator enter `which su` , it should show the location of su binary other than `/system/xbin/` ( in my case it shows in the `/su/bin/su` location ). You can leave a comment to show the result in your case. Thanks
- In Su app settings, option to install SuperSU as system app is greyed out and the text reads that this option is not available being systemless root

[image]

- Some apps which have their path hard coded to search for su in above location will fail. [ES Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) is one such app, which will not work with root privileges, [though rooted](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus5x/comments/4jlcnw/help_cant_enable_root_for_es_file_explorer_after/) - not a reliable method, since the app can be updated

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm what it shows in case of normal root

Comment: I think someone in Kitkat can check

Comment: @Izzy responded in chat room saying that there is no output, in case of normal root, so for now we could take it that systemless root gives the output as mentioned