# Can a Samsung receive OTA updates normally with a systemless root?

Tags: samsung, ota-update, systemless-root

If a systemless root is done, will software updates still appear in settings/show up as a notification that there is a new update available?

In case it does show up, can you download and install the update directly from the settings app even though the phone is rooted?

From what I read, systemless roots are great because they allow you to update a rooted Android without unrooting it. Is this the case or have I misread something?

Another thing I was curious about is if you root your Android via systemless root, would the phone status stay "official" or will it be "modified"/"custom"? And would a factory reset unroot a phone that has been rooted via systemless root?

Comment: Related: [What is "systemless root"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132753/44325) (the answer touches about OTA update)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I root a Samsung without a computer(using no computer root method) will I receive Software Update normally?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262473/if-i-root-a-samsung-without-a-computerusing-no-computer-root-method-will-i-rec)

Answer (score 1):

No, no matter how you root your device, you won't get Android updates unless you flash a newer rom on Android which may cause you to have to wipe your phone. It also depends on what you use, if you use Magisk, KingoRoot or CF-Autoroot, then it may hide the root, but all jailbreaking apps try to hide the root so that you don't get stopped from using apps.

- Edit:
  Factory resetting removes root, but depending on your oem, they may always be able to tell if you root your phone. Like if you have a Note 3 that is rooted, it starts up and says Void Warranty on the top left. Samsung will always know that you rooted your device, even if you remove the root.

Comment: although I am not Samsung user this is contradictory to my (mothers) Huawei experience, where FOTA is overwriting ramdisk.img (boot.img) automatically, causing loss of magisk su each time. there is also Magisk [OTA survival](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/ota.html) guide (for non-samsung devices)